# Moving a file from machine1 folder1 to machine1 folder2 using machine2

Tags: networking, file-sharing, nfs

I have a machine I use as server (transmissiondeamon, plex, fileserver, that  kind of stuff) This machine is headless so if I need to move a file from my transmission download folder to my plex movie folder on the same machine I use a ssh connection. This works fine for me. But now i need to make this user friendly for my wife to do it her self. This means I need to make this possible in a gui. My solution would be that I make a file share with nfs of the two folders and make a link in the file browser my wife uses. But when I move file's this way I think that the data of this file is send from server to laptop and then back to server. No problem with small files but with large files or folders this is a lot off unnecessary load for the network and the moving/copying of a file takes a lot of time.

Is there a smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use samba, since 4.1 it's possible to let samba move files server side: https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Server-Side_Copy

Though I'm unsure about your wifes operating system and therefore client support of the feature. Check the [wiki](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Server-Side_Copy#Client_Support) regarding that.

Also you could let transmission do the moving after the torrent download is completed: https://trac.transmissionbt.com/wiki/Scripts

Comment: Thanks for the sugestion Jakob. I'm looking in to the server side copying. By the way my wife uses a Kubuntu 15.04 laptop.

Comment: Again thanks. Jakob Lenfers! This server side coping is exactly what i was looking for! I understand that both folders have to be on the same share. Do you know if it is a problem the folders are not on the same disk? and if i make to separate links to the specific folders of the share on  my wife laptop?

Comment: No, I just know that Samba implemented that feature a couple of month ago and saved it as a useful addition. :)